# Cannot get Glob to function as expected

Tags: php, glob

I have been trying the simple idea of starting small and building up, however I cannot get the Glob function to work at all. Even the basic examples I have found on websites. I have been searching for over an hour and still not working, wondering if either I am missing something or I am having a brain fart.

I am trying the simple code of:

```
    <?php
        $files = glob("/products/cd400/*.pdf");

    ?>

    <div id="output">

    <P><u>List of help files:</p>
        <P><?=$files?></p>

    </div>
```

Now I know that glob starts on your root and from my root folder it literally goes

> /products/cd400

I am starting to despair and really hoping for some help.

As an edit, forgot to say this just returns:

> List of help files:
>
> Array

Thank you

Comment: you can also:

`<P><?=join('<br/>', $files)?></p>`

Comment: none of these things are working, I think I have a IIS SQL server error somewhere

Comment: how is file system linked to IIS SQL server o_O ?

Comment: user access, dont think its checking any directory with my current user for some reason, denying everything

Answer (score 1):

[glob](http://pk1.php.net/glob) output will be an array

Try this...

```
print_r($files);
```

or

```
<?php
    foreach(glob("/products/cd400/*.pdf") as $pdf)   
    {  
        echo "Filename: " . $pdf. "<br />";      
    }  
?>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I added it to the bit under list of help files and now I get Array ( ) 1, Am I just being stupid here?

Comment: @Marriott81 If you see just `Array ()` it means no file matched.

Comment: @RahilWazir thanks for the reply, thats very strange I have 32 pdf files in that dir =\

Comment: @user1844933 thanks, I have gone from array to just a single number 1 on my screen however

Comment: I will, however its literally just showing the number 1 not any files?

just tried the file on its own little test file, not in my main php file, and its still not running?

Comment: possible I have a server issue, getting error 32, will look into it and see if that is effecting it

Comment: and make it sure existence of folder and files... folder name is case sensitive also...